# Filter out text to remove directory and leave only file

Tags: bash

Running the following command `grep -r "TESTPROGS/" /home/am/test.txt` on this file:

```
AMPROGS/
AMPROGS/TqaWhkhiCx8ymy8lIR2p.SH
AMPROGS/iOryQxYtZwhkl0x7CcmW.SH
AMPROGS/a14KbHWjbnWehzkmDWuv.SH
TESTPROGS/
TESTPROGS/HRH7B76fogxwX6zEe7w8.SH
TESTPROGS/m0np3yEbpplqk36wVJ1l
TESTPROGS/t8ZCuJMgZO9accbjoDnp
```

Returns the following result:

```
TESTPROGS/
TESTPROGS/HRH7B76fogxwX6zEe7w8.SH
TESTPROGS/m0np3yEbpplqk36wVJ1l
TESTPROGS/t8ZCuJMgZO9accbjoDnp
```

How would I now strip out TESTPROGS/ completely, so I have this:

```
HRH7B76fogxwX6zEe7w8.SH
m0np3yEbpplqk36wVJ1l
t8ZCuJMgZO9accbjoDnp
```

Comment: Another way in `Awk` along with the answers below - `awk '/TESTPROGS\//{gsub(/TESTPROGS\//,""); if (NF) print }' file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wuith GNU grep:

```
grep -Po 'TESTPROGS/\K.*' /home/am/test.txt
```

Output:

```
HRH7B76fogxwX6zEe7w8.SH
m0np3yEbpplqk36wVJ1l
t8ZCuJMgZO9accbjoDnp
```

> `\K`: discards the already matching part

Answer (score 5):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F'/' '$1=="TESTPROGS" && $2 != "" {print $2}' /home/am/test.txt
```

`-F/` splits the lines of input into fields separated by `/`. `$1=="TESTPROGS"` checks if the first field equals `TESTPROGS`. If that is true and the second field is not empty, it prints the second field.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/TESTPROGS\/.+/' file

TESTPROGS/HRH7B76fogxwX6zEe7w8.SH
TESTPROGS/m0np3yEbpplqk36wVJ1l
TESTPROGS/t8ZCuJMgZO9accbjoDnp
```

or

```
awk -F'/' '/TESTPROGS\/.+/{print $2}' filterout.awk

HRH7B76fogxwX6zEe7w8.SH
m0np3yEbpplqk36wVJ1l
t8ZCuJMgZO9accbjoDnp
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
for line in $(grep -r "TESTPROGS/" /home/am/test.txt); do basename "${line}"; done
```